# Filtering in Many to Many relationship in django

Tags: python, django

I have two classes Location and Supplier. A supplier supplies its products to one or more cities.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    cities = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    supplied_cities = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
```

Now I have to get all the Suppliers for a city, from a list of Cities. 
for example: If London is clicked, I should get the all the suppliers related to London. How should I do this?

```
Supplier.objects.filter(supplied_cities= 1)
```

Above shell command lists all suppliers from city 1 (int). But I have to capture the City Name from the web page and filter based on it?

View:

```
def my_view(request):
    cityName = request.GET['place']
    sellers = Supplier.objects.filter(supplied_cities= Location.objects.get(cities=cityName))
    context = {'sellers' : sellers }
    return render_to_response('results.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
{% for sellers in object_list %}
<li>  {{ sellers.name }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
def my_view(request):
    city_name = request.GET.get('place')
    sellers = Supplier.objects.filter(supplied_cities__cities=city_name)
    context = {'sellers' : sellers }
    return render_to_response('results.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And then your template:

```
{% for seller in sellers %}
    <li>  {{ seller.name }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

You misnamed your context variable.

I also highly recommend either using [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/) or the [url dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) for passing arguments to your views.

```
url(r'^/sellers/(?P<city>\w+)/$', my_view, name='sellers')

def my_view(request, city):
    # rest of your view
```

Comment: Thanks. Filter works in shell command. How should I create the URL? For example, currently I am using http://127.0.0.1:8000/locations/search/london/ but it looks like context variable 'sellers' is always empty.